# Convert TS interface keys to type values

Tags: node.js, typescript, sqlite

I'm trying to be a bit fancy in a database table class. I'd like the user to be able to just pass a row interface (or class if necessary) and have the table class infer how to create the table.

```
interface Row {
   rowid: number
}

class Table<T extends Row> {
   getRowDefinition(){
     // magically use T to create col definitions
   }
 
   createTable(){
     const defs = this.getRowDefinition();
     const cols = defs.map(def => {
        switch(def.type){
          case 'string':
           return `${def.name} TEXT`;
          case 'number':
           return `${def.name} INTEGER;
        }
     });
     const sql = 'CREATE TABLE ...'; // use cols, etc
   }
}

interface MyRow extends Row {
  name: string
  age: number
}

class MyTable extends Table<MyRow> {}
```

Comment: You haven't *exactly* asked a question here.  Could you clarify what you want?  Comments in example code alone don't constitute a question.

Comment: After you improve the question, it may be that [this](https://tsplay.dev/WY4Ovm) is what you're looking for.  If so I could possibly write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I assume OP wants to use the type `T` in the program's logic to create a database table schema based on `T`'s field types...

Comment: @jcalz yep that's basically it

Comment: @jcalz although the only thing passed to `getRowDefinition` is an interface which is only known through the generic type ie when delcaring it as `MyTable<RowType>` so a configuration object is not sent with fields like `name` and `type`, otherwise I'd just loop through that.

Comment: @samala7800 so as I mentioned in my answer, there's no way to do that, because all information related to thing like `type` and `interface` are wiped off when TS compiler generates JS code. So you don't have that data to check at runtime. Your best bet will be to use a `class` and check it's properties.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript types are removed at compile time and so they are not available in run-time.

You can use `instanceof` if you create some classes to determine each row type, and use `typeof` to determine the type of a variable in run-time.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof